# convert Json to dataframe from api codes

Tags: python, json

I am new to python, I have extracted some reviews from a website and I used the api to import my data in python and the format is in json. I want to convert this json to a dataframe in python. Can someone guide me on how to perform this please.

Below is the code for importing the api extraction in json format

```
import requests

params = {
  "api_key": "abc",
  "format": "json"
}
r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/runs/ttx8PT-EL6Rf/data', params=params)
print(r.text)
```

My output is as follows:

```
{
     "name": "136",
     "Date": "September 07, 2019",
     "comment": "enjoy a lovely moment"
    },
    {
     "name": "135",
     "Date": "July 15, 2019",
     "comment": "I was there for my honeymoon. The hotel was simply wooww and wonderful. ALL the hotel staff was extremely friendly and made us felt at home. Deluxe Room very nice. Spa, hammam sauna very good. I indeed appreciated the hotel, without forgetting its meals, simply amazing quality and variety, i ate a lot. Relaxing moments with birds chirping, different swings to chill. Overall, I shall visit again. Thanks Azuri & Marideal."
    },
    {
     "name": "134",
     "Date": "June 12, 2019",
     "comment": "Had an amazing stay for 2 nights.\nThe cleanliness of the room is faultless"
    },
```

and it continues.
Can you please help me to convert this into a dataframe in python please please.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import simplejson as json  

data = json.dumps(r) #convert to json
data = json.loads(data)
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) #convert json to dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks but I am having an issue:
```
TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable
```
Can you please help me

Comment: ahhh,  add the .json() to your request ```r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/runs/ttx8PT-EL6Rf/data', params=params).json() ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "from_dict" as below.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
```

also your data most be list of dicts.

```
data = [
{...} , {...} , {,,,}
]
```